# Prisma/Client : WeakRef is not defined

Tags: node.js, prisma

when doing any thing using prisma/client it shows the error

```
Message: Error in Prisma Client request: 

WeakRef is not defined

Query:
{
  "modelName": "Users",
  "operation": "findMany",
  ...
}
```

[EDIT] : it's solved i was using node 12 instead of node 16

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your environment? What environment are you running in, what kind of query are you running, is it failing on a specific line of code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i was using node 12.xx i upgraded to node 16 it's working now

Comment: Node version 12 is no longer supported by Prisma.